# Prove factorial problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\forall n\in\mathbb N$ $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\n\end{matrix}\right)$.

Prove that $C_{n+1}=\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\n\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\n-1\end{matrix}\right)$

I tried many ways but got nothing. Appreciate any tips.
My attempt: By defining, $C_{n+1}= \dfrac{1}{n+2}\left(\begin{matrix}2n+2\\n+1\end{matrix}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n+2}\dfrac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!}=\dfrac{1}{n+2}*\dfrac{(2n+2)(2n+1)n!}{(n+1)^2n!n!}$

$=\dfrac{1}{n+2}\dfrac{2(2n+1)n!}{(n+1)n!}$

Comment: See [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Answer (score 7):

You’ve misstated the result: you want to show that

$$C_n=\binom{2n}n-\binom{2n}{n-1}\;,$$

not that

$$C_{n+1}=\binom{2n}n-\binom{2n}{n-1}\;.$$

Note that $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=\binom{2n-1}n$, so

$$\binom{2n}{n-1}=\frac{2n}{n+1}\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=\frac{n}{n+1}\left(\binom{2n-1}{n-1}+\binom{2n-1}n\right)\;.$$

Now use Pascal’s identity and a little algebra.

Comment: You mean the problem is wrong?? you mean I have to convert $C_n$ from the first form to the second term? Honestly, this problem is not my problem, a friend asked me help him to solve it. I can't figure it out. That's why I made question here.

Comment: @user73195: Yes, you have to show that $$\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n=\binom{2n}n-\binom{2n}{n-1}\;;$$ the $C_{n+1}$ in your second line should be $C_n$. (You can check a couple of small numerical examples.)

Comment: Gooooooot you. OMG.!!! It took me more than 4 hours to prove a wrong problem and got nothing. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user73195: You’re welcome. (That has to be awfully frustrating.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to simplify the second term: $\binom{2n}{n-1}=\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n-1)!(n+1)!}= \dfrac{(2n)!}{\frac{n!}{n}\cdot (n!\cdot (n+1))}= \dfrac{n}{n+1}\cdot \binom{2n}{n} \Rightarrow C_n = \binom{2n}{n} - \dfrac{n}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}= \left(1-\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)\binom{2n}{n} = \dfrac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: Thanks for respond, but I don't get what you mean by that. What is the second term in the expression above? I don't get how you have that second term since we have to prove it, we can't use it before proving, right?

Answer (score 1):

$$C_{n+1}=\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\n\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\n-1\end{matrix}\right)=\frac{1}{n+1}[\frac{(2n)!(n+1))}{n!n!}-\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n-1)!}]=\\\frac{1}{n+1}\frac{2n!}{n!}[\frac{n+1}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}]=\\ \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{2n!}{n!n!}(n+1-\frac{n!}{(n-1)!})=\\ \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{2n!}{n!n!}(n+1-n)=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$$